# stretch my container div

Tags: css

You know when you stare at something for sooo long you go cross eyed. I am at that point.

All I want to do is stretch the div, **vertically** based on the content inside.

Very very simple code here , I have stripped back a lot. But this is the essential stuff, I think its a margin:auto issue that I need, maybe wrong...

I cant doa  fiddle site currently unavailable.

So here is the code:

html:

```
<div class="agencyBoxAbout">
    <div class="agencyText">
        <blockquote class="blockquotebig">blah dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker dee blah dee blah lorem ipsum kiss my ricker</blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.agencyText {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    padding:10px;
    height:100%;
}

.agencyBoxAbout {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    min-height:150px;
    position:relative;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

.blockquotebig {
    /*background: url("../images/bigquote.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;*/
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 52px;
    width: 390px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `position:absolute` in `.agencyText`. If you remove that (or use `relative`, for example) then it should work.

Comment: but I want to position text absolutely within the parent div. I see that an absolute block cannot stretch a relative postioned element, but wondered what the workaround was.

Comment: Can you not use `position:relative` on `.agencyText`? It's difficult to see how that would affect you without seeing more code really.

Comment: yeah seemingly height 100% in agencytext affects it, so relative and setting margins seems the way to go

Comment: Yeah fixed it. My bad, thanks for making this "relatively" easy ;)